# Haskell Set Comprehensions

Tags: list, haskell, set, list-comprehension

Is there any possibility, such as a language extension, to use the syntax of list comprehensions syntax for `Data.Set` sets?

**Example:**

```
f :: Set a -> Set b -> Set (a,b)
f xs ys = [(x,y) | x <- xs , y <- ys] -- this is the set comprehension
```

Since sets are the mathematical structure that inspired list comprehensions it would be kind of strange not to have any possibility of using them on sets.

And yes, I am aware of `MonadComprehensions` for using the list-comp syntax with any `Monad`/`MonadPlus` type but AFAIK sets can't even be monads because of the `Ord` constraint in most functions.

Comment: `sets are the mathematical structure that inspired list comprehensions` But Data.Set is not that structure `because of the Ord constraint`.

Answer (score 9):

## In Theory, No

There are no language extensions which allow for "set comprehensions."

The differences between a `Set` and a `List` are:

1. The `Set` is unordered while the `List` is ordered
2. The elements of the `Set`are unique while the `List` may have duplicate elements
3. The type of the `Set` is an instance of `Ord` while the `List` has no type restrictions.

You can see that all possible `Set`s are a strict subset of all possible `List`s. This means that we can achieve "set comprehension" simply be using a list comprehension and converting it to a `Set`. Lazy evaluation will *often* make the "set generation" efficient deriving from most *finite* list comprehensions. However, list comprehensions resulting in *infinite* lists are unlikely to result in efficient "set comprehension."

**Example:**

```
import Data.Set

set :: Ord a => Set a
set = fromList [x * y | x <- [1..10], y <- [1..10]]
```

## In Practice, Yes

Using the [**`set-monad`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad-0.2.0.0/docs/Data-Set-Monad.html) package, you can define a `Set` as an instance of  `Monad` and using the language extension `MonadComprehensions` you can achieve a "set comprehension".

**Example:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-}
import Data.Set.Monad

set1 :: Set (Int,Int)
set1 = do 
         a <- fromList [1 .. 4]
         b <- fromList [1 .. 4]
         return (a,b)

-- Look a "set comprehension"
set2 :: Set (Int,Int)
set2 = [ (a,b) | (a,b) <- set1, even a, even b ]
```

*Use whichever method makes the most sense for your project. Profile both before making a decision!*

Comment: Err... how would lazy evaluation make set generation efficient? You have to evaluate all of the list to create the set. Lazy evaluation doesn't seem to do anything at all here.

Comment: @Cubic You'll won't generate the entire list and then generate the entire set. The operation will fuse due to lazy evaluation, so if I generate a large list of  duplicates of a single element, I won't incur the memory overhead, as the set will lazily draw from the list and create the singleton set.

Comment: Depending on fromList's implementation, in the best of worlds and with a lot of luck and a bit of optimism, if the list is large laziness can give the GC a chance to sweep the head of the list while the tail is being fed to the set builder. But in the real world I doubt there'd be any effect indeed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that both `xs` and `ys` in OP's example are sets, not ordinary lists.

Comment: @Zeta He should add type annotations then to be explicit. It appeared to be a list comprehension from the syntax.

Comment: @MathiasDolidon I see nothing in [`fromList`'s implementation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.3/docs/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/src/Data-Set.html#fromList) that would keep the entire list in memory, so I see no reason why this wouldn't happen in the real world. Your doubts seem a bit too pessimistic to me.

Comment: A function that diverges on infinite inputs isn't called lazy by most people.

Comment: @sepp2k The GC's mood. :) 
n.m. the lazy one would be the list provider, not the set builder.

Comment: *"There are no language extensions which allow for "set comprehensions.""* One could probably use QuasiQuotations like `[sc|…]`. But TemplateHaskell doesn't count.

Comment: @Zeta's first remark makes me wonder, sidetracking though : in something like Clojure, one wouldn't care whether the source data be a list, a set, or anything else. It would just comply with the `ISeq` interface, be lazy and let anybody do whatever they want. Would there be a typeclass that'd be an equivalent to Clojure's ISeq ?

Comment: @MathiasDolidon perhaps `Foldable` or `ListLike`. It would be interesting if instances of `Foldable` could be generalize to allow for arbitrary "list comprehension" syntax.

Comment: @n.m., that's because most people conflate "strict" with "eager" and "non-strict" with "lazy". But these are distinct ideas, and it's possible for one thing to be lazier than another even if they are equally strict (under appropriate assumptions). Notably, if a data structure is implemented as an abstract data type, it can be "effectively strict" in its structure while actually having a lazy spine. Functions that operate on the structure can be considered "strict" even if they don't always force the whole structure, or even most of it. This can make semantic reasoning simpler.